# «ff.»: «Folgende» oder «fortfolgende»?

Tags: abbreviation

Wie es der Titel bereits sagt, möchte ich wissen, ob die Abkürzung «ff.» eigentlich für «folgende» oder  «*fort*folgende» steht. In diversen Forenbeiträgen werden – mit einer Tendenz zu ersterem – beide Meinungen vertreten. Allerdings habe ich bisher noch keine gesichterte Quelle gefunden.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bei Abkürzungen wird der Plural manchmal durch eine Buchstabenverdopplung ausgedrückt (vgl. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/abkuerzungen)). Somit steht *ff.* für

> [*ff.*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ff_):  und folgende [Seiten]

Comment: +1, weiteres Beispiel: Jgg. = Jahrgänge; auf Italienisch gibt es übrigens ähnliche Abkürzungen: pp. = pagine (Seiten), ffss. = Ferrovie dello Stato (Staatsbahn-en)

Comment: +1 dito - schön auch: Abkürzung EEUU - ausgeschrieben *estados unidos* - zu deutsch „Vereinigte Staaten“, USA

Comment: Auch in der Musik: p = piano (leise), pp = pianissimo (sehr leise). entsprechend f = forte (laut), ff = fortissimo (sehr laut). Moderne Komponisten erweitern dieses Schema. Ich habe schon Stücke gesungen, in denen alles zwischen ppppp (unhörbar leise) und fffff (unter Mobilisierung der letzten Reserven, und ohne Rücksicht auf die Gesundheit der Stimmbänder) notiert war.

Answer (score 7):

Wenn man nach 'ff Abkürzungen' googelt, findet man u.a. [Abkürzung: ff](http://www.abkuerzungen.org/abkuerzung-1294.html) so dass "(und) folgende" auf jeden Fall richtig ist, wenn man der Seite glaubt. (Wenn man der Seite nicht glaubt, dann würde ich darauf hinweisen, dass Sprache lebt und auf lange Sicht de facto das richtig ist, was sich im Gebrauch durchsetzt :-)).

Die Antwort "folgende" wird auch auf verschiedenen anderen Seiten bestätigt, z.B. noch. ['F'](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F)  oder [Folge 8: Dipl.-Ing., EKG und u. U. auch der Pkw oder
dies und jenes über Abkürzungen](http://www.studis-online.de/Studieren/Richtig_schreiben/abkuerzungen.php).

Andere Seiten weisen darauf hin, dass es das Wort 'fortfolgende' eigentlich gar nicht gibt, der Duden z.B. kennt es nicht. Wenn man sich auf den Standpunkt stellt, erübrigt sich die Diskussion, aber meines Erachtens ist das nicht so gewichtig, die deutsche Sprache erlaubt es, Worte zusammenzusetzen, gelegentlich mit der Gefahr, dass ein unklarer Begriff dabei herauskommt. Bei 'fortfolgend' ist das m.E. so: das Wort wird durchaus verwendet, ich würde -- als Muttersprachler -- persönlich keinen Bedeutungsunterschied wahrnehmen, wenn irgendwo an Stelle von '(und) folgende' '(und) fortfolgende' stehen würde, höchstens, dass das Wort 'fortfolgende' weniger gebräuchlich ist und seine Verwendung in der Umgangssprache, sagen wir, auffällig wäre.

Ich bin aber kein Sprachwissenschaftler, die mögen das anders sehen.

Interessanter ist der Unterschied zwischen 'f.' und 'ff.', der auch auf der oben verlinkten Seite [Abkürzungen](http://www.studis-online.de/Studieren/Richtig_schreiben/abkuerzungen.php) erläutert wird.

Sorry, ich weiss, dass das keine eindeutige Antwort ist. Die gibt es aber vermutlich auch nicht.

Comment: +1: kein Wörterbuch kennt *"fortfolgen"* oder *"fortfolgende"*

Answer (score 5):

Das Problem bei „folgende (Seite[n])“ ist, dass nicht erkennbar ist, ob sich der Bezug nur auf die folgende Seite oder auf noch mehr Seiten erstreckt.

[Wie Takkat richtig feststellte](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3211/392), macht die Verdoppelung deutlich, dass mehr als eine Folgeseite referenziert wird. Die Formulierung „fortfolgende“ resultiert m. E. weniger aus der Verdoppelung selber, als eher aus dem Problem, dies auch sprachlich (z. B. in einem Vortrag, einer Vorlesung) deutlich zu machen.

Hier wird die ausführliche Variante „und folgende Seiten“ wohl häufig als zu umständlich empfunden. Daher die „Kurzfassung“ „fortfolgende“, die einerseits für den Zuhörer eindeutig, andererseits möglichst knapp ist.

Das Schema lautet also in etwa:

> Abkürzung: *f.* - ausgeschrieben: *„und folgende [Zähleinheit]“* - gesprochen: *„folgende“*

und

> Abkürzung: *ff.* - ausgeschrieben: *„und folgende [Zähleinheiten]“* - gesprochen: *„fortfolgende“*

Answer (score 1):

*ff.* ist der Plural von *f.*. Die Pluralbildung durch Verdopplung ist im Elfenbeinturm recht beliebt.Hier handelt es sich um neueres Latein, aber analog auch z. B. *ff* = *fortissimo* oder sogar *§§*.

*f.* wiederum steht für *folio*, also Seite.

Answer (score -1):

Leider habe ich keine Quellenangabe, aber ich meine mich sehr gut zu erinnern, dass vor allem bei wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten (Thesis etc.) "S. 123 f." nur die folgende Seite 124 meinte und "S. 123 ff." quasi aber der 125. Seite zum Einsatz kommt.

So benutze ich das in meiner Thesis. Hier wird's auch disktuiert sowie meine These vertreten: http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/ff-und-f-was-ist-der-unterschied#answers

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt habe ich beim Überfliegen (länger halte ich es auf gutefrage meist nicht aus) keine Aussage gefunden, die deine These stützt, ff. beziehe sich auf die übernächste Seite.

Comment: "S. 123 f." - die Seiten 123 und 124. "S. 123 ff." - mindestens die Seiten 123-125, möglicherweise aber noch mehr. Nach meinem Verständnis ist Gegenstand der Frage aber nicht die praktische Bedeutung der beiden Abkürzungen, sondern wofür genau _ff._ steht.

Comment: +1 für O.R.Mapper. Zumindest die Mehrheit der Antworten auf der verlinkten Seite spricht dagegen. Ich würde mal den Professor fragen, wie er das mit dem *ff* in der Thesis sieht, bevor da ein Lapsus passiert...

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass die Aussage nicht durch die verlinkte Frage gestützt wird - wozu sollte denn eine Abkürzung in der beschriebenen Bedeutung gut sein? Wenn "S. 123 f." *nur* die Seite 124 bezeichnet, wieso sollte man denn nicht direkt "S. 124" schreiben? Noch absurder wird es, wenn "S. 123 ff." *nur* die Seite 125 bezeichnet - wozu denn das Kopfrechentraining beim Verweis auf Seiten?