# Use of abbrevation "ff."

Tags: usage, abbreviation

From Süddeutsche Zeitung:

> Der derzeit tobende "Gamergate" dagegen, Spieler-Gate, sieht so aus: Gewisse Gamer (siehe oben, Männer ff.) reagieren auf die von der US-Medienkritikerin Anita Sarkeesian gestellte Frage, ob das Frauenbild in Online-Ballerspielen nicht das von ziemlich bedauernswerten Tröpfen sei, mit Morddrohungen.

I've looked up the use of [ff.](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff.), and I'm still confused what "Männer folgende" would mean. Also, why is ff. used after the noun it refers to, as in "Siehe Seite 303 ff."?

Comment: It means "and the following [pages, items...]". So "see page 303 and the pages following 303".

Comment: Related: [«ff.»: «Folgende» oder «fortfolgende»?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/ff-folgende-oder-fortfolgende)

Comment: Have you seen [f.](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f.) as well? And their foreign language counterparts in the side bar to the left? The English pages, for instance, have very informative **Usage notes**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"ff" means "[und] folgende", usually in references to pages, when you want to say "don't just look at that page but also a few pages after that": "Seite 300ff" can be pages 300 to 305.

Without knowing the whole article, I would assume "Männer" refers to another section in that article (titled "Männer"), and "Männer ff" refers to that section and the next few sections.

To me, "ff" or just "f" (one following page) vs "pages 1, 2, and 4" is a bit old style, when people would manually maintain their references and did not want to update all references after inserting text.

Comment: I agree that it’s old style. Nowadays, nobody would reduplicate an abbreviation to indicate plural. It’s also lazy, because software can automatically handle complex references. Finally, _f._ and _ff._ are commonly only used with numeric references, primarily page numbers, sometimes chapters or section.

Comment: Isn't _1 ff._ different to _"pages 1, 2, and 4"_ since p. 3 is missing in the latter?

Comment: @GeriBroser could be --- I don't use that style. This was just an example to illustrate different styles, not claiming that they mean the same.